# Storing Image path using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a controller which handles the upload functionality of the music file. The controller uses this [Laravel getID3 package](https://github.com/owen-oj/laravel-getid3) to parse the metadata from the music file and store in the database.
My code looks like this

```
if($request->hasfile('songs')){
            foreach ( $request->file('songs') as $key => $file){
                $track = new getID3($file);
                $tifo = $track->extractInfo();
                $artistName = $track->getArtist();
                $songName = $track->getTitle();
                $albumName = $track->getAlbum();
                $extension = $track->getFileFormat();
                $thumbnail = $track->getArtwork(true);
                $thumbnails = 'artwork-'.time().'.'.$thumbnail->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $location = time() .uniqid().'.' . $extension;
                $file->storeAs('public/songs',$location);
                //$file->storeAs('public/sthumbs',$thumbnails);

                $file = new MusicUpload();

                $music_upload_file = new MusicUpload();
                $music_upload_file->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
                $music_upload_file->filename = $songName;
                $music_upload_file->extension = $extension;
                $music_upload_file->artistname = $artistName;
                $music_upload_file->albumname = $albumName;
                $music_upload_file->location = $location;
                $music_upload_file->thumbnail = $thumbnails;
                $music_upload_file->save();
            }
        }
```

What I want to do is to store both the music file as well as the thumbnail of the file in the database.

Here the `$thumbnails` will store the image in the specified folder but the image is unreadable, i.e. it has the same file size as the music and doesn't contain the artwork which is to be stored and retrieved.
If I don't include the `$thumbnails` part, the package default stores to the temp folder which is inaccessible to the controller.

So how do I write the code such that the thumbnail(artwork) of the music gets stored in the correct folder and it can display the output too.

Comment: `$file` is the file you uploaded, right? So obviously that will not be your image. `$thumbnail` is your image.  The docs for the package you are using say "*(`getArtwork()`) will return an UploadedFile instance*", so did you try `$thumbnail->storeAs('public/songs', $thumbnails);`?

Answer (score 0):

You can store it to storage folder.

```
 Storage::disk('public')->put($location,File::get($file));
```

Don't forget to run `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: It will store into your **storage** folder and you can access it by `Storage::url('file_path)`.

Comment: `Storage::disk('public/songs')`  doesn't work. I need to store files within subfolder of storage folder

Comment: change here - `$location = 'songs/'.time() .uniqid().'.' . $extension;`

then 

    Storage::disk('public')->put($location,File::get($file));